# Cross Platform Mobile UI

Tags: html, layout, mobile, jquery-mobile, user-interface

So this is a general discussion question. I am building a really fancy UI (based on mocks from designers) and a key requirement is that this UI is fully cross platform including mobile devices and different screen sizes.

I have previously used different frameworks such as jQuery Mobile, but the standard layout elements are simply insufficient for the UI I am building; it has specific looking form fields and custom elements such as a calendar.

I started of with jQuery Mobile and soon realized I am having to write CSS to override jQM styling most of the time. That made me realize perhaps I am better off starting from scratch and later manipulating the DOM with jQuery.

What is the best approach here? Should I write my own HTML5/CSS from scratch, using only widely supported tags and classes? Or should I go for an existing framework and customize it as I need?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on a lot of things. Is it for the web, or is it native (Hybrid app)?

If it's for the web, I tend to keep away from frameworks like jQM as although it is a brilliant product, I think they are just too big for mobile data connections.

On the other hand, not relying on a framework might then mean you'll spend more time on browser quirks for a fancy UI. Do you have the resources to provide [support for devices like a framework can](http://jquerymobile.com/gbs/)? Do you even need to? Understanding when to use a framework I guess comes with experience.

My conclusion would be gained from how much time you think it will need extending/deviating from a framework vs writing from scratch. A hard figure to estimate, but that's how I'd do it.